# I want my program to display an error message when the user inputs anything other than an integer and loop it back

Tags: java, string, exception, if-statement, int

I am doing a project for my CS class and have everything done except for when users input anything that isn't an integer when I ask for their height, it gives an error.
I'm not sure how to catch the exception. 
Here is a snippet of my source code.
I'm a beginner and I really appreciate the help.

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "This program calculates tidal volume.", "Tidal Volume Calculator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

    while (flag3 == true)
    {
        sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your sex?");

        if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase("male") || sex.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
        {
            while (flag2 == true) 
            {
                height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your height? (48-84 inches or 114-213 centimeters) \nEnter whole numbers only."));

                if(height <= 84 && height >= 48)
                {
                    malePbwInch = 50 + 2.3 * (height - 60);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + "'s predicted body weight is: " + malePbwInch);
                    flag2 = false;
                    flag3 = false;
                }
                if(height <= 213 && height >= 114)
                {
                    malePbwCm = 50 + .91 * (height - 152.4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + "'s predicted body weight is: " + malePbwCm);
                    flag2 = false;
                    flag3 = false;
                }
                if(height > 84 && height < 114 || height < 48 || height > 213)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid height. Please try again.");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        malePbwInch = Integer.parseInt(height);
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid height. Please try again.");
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are parsing the input to integer, there can occur exception. Parse input inside try block and in catch you can display message to input a number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement **exception handling**.

```
try { 
height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your height? (48-84 inches or 114-213 centimeters) \nEnter whole numbers only."));
} catch (Exception e)
{
// this part gets executed when a non-int is given as input
//Print error message, etc
}
```

If you want you can also build a while-loop around this piece of code and only break out of it if no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `loop` and a `try..catch` block inside of it :

```
height = 0;
do{
    try{
        height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your height? (48-84 inches or 114-213 centimeters) \nEnter whole numbers only."));
    } catch (Exception e){
        // Display an error Pane
    }
} while(height == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a try/catch block in there, but it's at the wrong level. You need to wrap it around initial attempt to parse an integer, something like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "This program calculates tidal volume.", "Tidal Volume Calculator", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your name?");

while (flag3 == true)
{
    sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your sex?");

    if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase("male") || sex.equalsIgnoreCase("m"))
    {
        while (flag2 == true) 
        {
            try {
                height = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your height? (48-84 inches or 114-213 centimeters) \nEnter whole numbers only."));

                if(height <= 84 && height >= 48)
                {
                    malePbwInch = 50 + 2.3 * (height - 60);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + "'s predicted body weight is: " + malePbwInch);
                    flag2 = false;
                    flag3 = false;
                }
                if(height <= 213 && height >= 114)
                {
                    malePbwCm = 50 + .91 * (height - 152.4);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, name + "'s predicted body weight is: " + malePbwCm);
                    flag2 = false;
                    flag3 = false;
                }
                if(height > 84 && height < 114 || height < 48 || height > 213)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid height. Please try again.");
                }
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid height. Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Please note that the above is untested, it's just a simple change of your code to move the try block to its proper place.)